# Increase the length of textarea

Tags: html, css, angularjs, textarea

How to increase the length of `textarea`? Just changing the `maxlength` will work?

Here is the code snippet:

```
<textarea name="Testremarks" onchange="CheckValidChars(this);" onblur="CheckValidChars(this);" onkeypress="return isValidChars(event);" id="Testremarks" maxlength="250" cols="40" rows="9" ng-model="vm.TestCycleRemarks"></textarea>
```

Comment: Don't use inline handlers in Angular app. Use custom directive.

Comment: the "length" here is quite ambiguous ... do you mean the total numbers of characters allowed in your textarea or its length on the view?

Comment: yes total number of characters

Comment: Did u search at all? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp

Comment: @beginner then Lukas' answer is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxlength regulates the maximum Characters a textarea will hold so

```
<textarea maxlength="250">
```

Only allows 250 characters

```
<textarea maxlength="500">
```

will hold 500 characters

Hope this is helpfull :)

Comment: It will automaticly scroll i guess but you should just try it out!

Comment: yes i can scroll . Just need to change the max length. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem, glad i could help you :)

Comment: stack overflow allows to accept answer in 5 mins. Will accept it soon :)